# What is the difference between enctype and formenctype in HTML5?

Tags: html, forms, encoding

I was jsust wondering what the difference between the attributes `enctype` and `formenctype` in the HTML Living Standard (a.ka. the new HTML5 spec)? I've been reading the [HTML Standard for Developers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/), but still can't seem to see any real distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enctype` attribute appears on `<form>` elements and sets the default encoding type for that form.

The `formenctype` attribute appears on submit buttons (e.g. `<button>` elements) and overrides the encoding for the form when that submit button is used to trigger form submission.